# Customize response header with Microsoft-HTTPAPI Server

Tags: http, iis, windows-server, httpapi

I have a dictation service which is running on a **Windows Server**, behind a **Microsoft-HTTPAPI Server** which assuring a http communication to the service, I installed this service using a msi package (without any configuration) and it works.

Now I need to add a custom response header to the responses coming from this service.

I thought about enabling IIS, and configure it in a way to intercept requests but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If that service hooks to HTTP API directly, you won’t be able to use IIS to hijack it. Install a reverse proxy in front, and there you might modify the HTTP responses.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you have any recommendations for a proxy to use? I'm trying with Fiddler now but it's not free :/